# Python socket.error: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: linux, python-3.x, udp, datagram

Using Linux and Python, I want to send some data with broadcast:

```
d = b'109u433279423423423'    

import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

s.sendto(d, 0, ('192.168.0.255', 9))
```

I launch this script under root and get this error:

```
s.sendto(d, 0, ('192.168.0.255', 9)) socket.error: [Errno 13]
Permission denied
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You are trying to send to a broadcast address. It is not allowed, see manpage for sendto(2):

> **EACCES** (For  UDP  sockets)  An  attempt  was  made  to  send  to a network/broadcast address as though it was a unicast address.

Set the SO_BROADCAST option, if you actually mean to send to a broadcast address:

```
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
```

Comment: It is always like this on Windows: strange

Comment: UNIX specs: sendto - send a message on a socket: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sendto.html